# Is there an Ubuntu package for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS that I can install with templates for making a 4 sided (front & back) card?

Tags: 20.04

I need templates for making a 4 sided (front & back) greeting card.
I couldn't find anything looking through Synaptic package mgr or the Ubuntu Software
that came with 20.04 LTS.

Comment: You can use LibreOffice that comes installed in Ubuntu. For example, see [i want to create a Christmas card](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/i-want-to-create-a-christmas-card/29364) in Ask LibreOffice.

Comment: Thank you! I have used that method, successfully.
I appreciate your help.
This is solved for me.